# Your bundle is locked to ffi (1.11.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rake

I get this error when starting the rails server:
I've tried gem install, gem update, bundle update, bundle install.

```
Your bundle is locked to ffi (1.11.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of ffi
(1.11.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a version other than ffi (1.11.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
```

can you help? thank you!

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.5.3'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'shopify_app'
gem 'rails', '5.2.3'
gem 'redis'
gem 'devise'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.6.1'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'

end
```

this is my rake file:

```
require_relative 'config/application'

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Delete the bundler version mentioned in your Gemfile.lock

Comment: I've deleted bundler (>= 1.3.0) in my Gemfile.lock and it works now, could you maybe explain a little bit about the above reason? many thanks!:)

Comment: That should not work. The issue isn't with bundler. It is with that version of the `ffi` gem not being available.

Answer (score 22):

The issue you're hitting is that bundler could not find that version of `ffi`. You most likely installed it originally when creating the project or adding a gem. The `ffi` version `1.11.0` [was pulled from RubyGems](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/701).

Run `bundle update` on your project to get the latest version, which is `1.11.1` as of today. That should fix your issue as when you deploy next when heroku runs bundler, it will pick up that version from RubyGems.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and `bundle update ffi` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try update in mode conversative your dependencies:

```
bundle update --conservative ffi
```

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT

In my case it was that the repo was unsupported. I was dealing with **multiple dependency hells**. I say multiple because there was was RakeFile for the Rainforest project which kicked off multiple other gems/projects/repos with incompatible versions across. At least that's what I've understood. For more see [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Rainforest/issues/89#issuecomment-752263648) where a contributor says the repo needs updating

---

I was following the steps from [CocoaPods dev environment setup](https://guides.cocoapods.org/contributing/dev-environment.html) and when I was doing `rake bootstrap` I was getting the following error:

```
Your bundle is locked to codecov (0.1.14), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that
means the author of codecov (0.1.14) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a version other than codecov (0.1.14) that hasn't been removed in order
to install.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (7): [bundle install...]
/Users/honey/Rainforest/Cork/Rakefile:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

From within my `Rainforest` directory I tried doing `bundle update codecov` but I was getting:

> Could not locate Gemfile

If you notice you see the error is failing from within a *subdirectory* of my Rainforest directory ie `/Rainforest/Cork`.

So I just changed the directory to `/Users/honey/Rainforest/Cork` where I had a **Gemfile** and then just ran `bundle update codecov`. Then I was able to run `rake bootstrap` from my `Rainforest` directory

---

After that fix, still my dev environment wasn't fully setup. The docs say:

> To verify that everything is set up, run: `CocoaPods/bin/pod --help`

When I did that I was getting this error:

> Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
>
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I did an `ls` and found the following items:

```
CLAide
CocoaPods
Core
Cork
Molinillo
Nanaimo
README.md
RELEASING.md
Rakefile
Xcodeproj
claide-completion
cocoapods-acknowledgements
cocoapods-deintegrate
cocoapods-docs
cocoapods-downloader
cocoapods-plugins
cocoapods-search
cocoapods-stats
cocoapods-trunk
cocoapods-try
fourflusher
pod-template
shared
```

Meaning there was no `Gemfile` in my current directory.

I changed directory into `CocoaPods` and saw a `Gemfile` in there. From there I just ran `bundle install` and then from my original `Rainforest` directory I was able to run `CocoaPods/bin/pod --help` successfully.

FWIW when I ran `bundle install` I got the following warning:

> Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.17.2) is older than the
> version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to
> the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

But that's a problem for another day.

What I understood was that for a library as big as CocoaPods there are multiple gems/projects and each error/warning message that you get is usually in regards to one gem/project and not others and if you change your directory and look into the files in regard to that gem/project then you'll get a better overview of what's going on wrong and where your command need to be ran from.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check that your firewall settings are allowing the requests. In my case, I had a physical firewall that was restricting certain types of requests. Once I allowed all requests, `bundle install` was able to successfully add all of the packages properly.